# ValidateUser of Forms Authentication issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sharepoint-2007, forms-authentication

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. And I am developing using ASP.Net + C# + .Net 3.5 + VSTS 2008 on SharePoint Server 2007. I am developing a custom Forms authentication based on Forms authentication interface. I am learning using Forms Authentication with SharePoint and my confusion is about this method -- ValidateUser of Forms Authentication, here is MSDN link,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.validateuser.aspx

My confusions are about which component will call ValidateUser method?

1. Do I need to call ValidateUser by myself (my application code), or depends on my needs (not always needed, depends on my application scenario);
2. Is ValidateUser is called by SharePoint code (not my own application code), if yes, when (i.e. in what situations will SharePoint calls ValidateUser method, or say in other words, what operation in SharePoint will trigger invocation of this method)?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValidateUser` method is called to verify that a username and password have been correctly entered for a user. It is called during the authentication process.

If your `web.config` file is configured to use your custom membership provider `ValidateUser` is called automatically if

- You use a standard control (like the [ASP.NET Login control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx)) for authentication in your page (this applies to both regular ASP.NET and SharePoint); or
- You use the default SharePoint Forms Authentication page (`/_layouts/login.aspx`). SharePoint will redirect unauthenticated users to this page if the content being accessed is blocked for anonymous users.

You will have to call `ValidateUser` yourself if you customize the default SharePoint login page and you don't use the ASP.NET Login control.

Comment: Thanks dariom! My question is, if I customize SharePoint login page and not using ASP.Net Login control, and for anonymous user, if the anonymous user access specific content which is blocked for anonymous users, will ValidateUser be called automatically?

Comment: When an anonymous user encounters blocked content SharePoint will redirect to the URL defined in the `web.config` (`loginUrl` attribute of the `forms` element). If this is a custom login page that **doesn't** use the ASP.NET Login control **you** will have to call `ValidateUser`. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: Thanks! My situation is, I have a customized login page (making some UI enhancements compared to SharePoint built-in login page) and use ASP.Net login control in the customized login page. And for anonymous user, if the anonymous user access specific content which is blocked for anonymous users, will ValidateUser be called automatically or just be redirected to my custom login page?

Comment: Thanks for clearing up your scenario. In your case, SharePoint will redirect to your custom login page when an anonymous tries to access restricted content. When the user submits the login page, the ASP.NET Login control will call `ValidateUser` for the membership provider configured in the `web.config`.